# conditional drop-down options

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display all the options that is in select box,if I first enter textbox value.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"/>
<select id="age">
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you need to use JS over here. Check if user entered value in textfield. untill hide/disable selectbox. if user press tab then enable that(listen on tab press action).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use javascript, HTML give you element for this type of requirement: datalist.

```
<input list="ages" />
<datalist id="ages">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
</datalist>
```

Hope this is what you want. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 0):

First you need to `hide` dropdown options.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"/>
<select id="age" style="display:none">
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Then with `js` show the dropdown field on`keydown` event.

```
$("#fname").keydown(function(){
 $("#age").show()
 });
```

working demo
[link](https://codepen.io/Akhil_dev/pen/vPBvKW)